# CSS: transform-style: preserve-3d AND overflow: hidden

Tags: css, overflow, transform

I have the banner on my website to display some clouds.
You can see it here: http://sharix.dyndns.org/StackOverflowVisible.php

These clouds should be confined within the banner box. This was working until today. It stopped without me touching anything. Now they seem to ignore the `overflow: hidden;` rule in the `default.css` file.
Adding a second `overflow: hidden;` rule to the `#world` div seems to work, but it breaks the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` rules. You can see it here: http://sharix.dyndns.org/StackOverflowHidden.php

How to have both the 3d-transforms and the overflow rules working, like it was until today?
The interesting part of the `default.css` file:

```
#header {
background: #4b6983;
border: 2px solid #7590ae;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow:0px 1px 5px black;
}

#viewport {
overflow: hidden;
background-image: $gradient;
background-image: $oGradient;
background-image: $mozGradient;
background-image: $webkitGradient;
background-image: $msGradient;
}

#header-content:hover {
z-index: 2;
transform: translateZ( 1px );
-moz-transform: translateZ( 1px );
-webkit-transform: translateZ( 1px );
-o-transform: translateZ( 1px );
-ms-transform: translateZ( 1px );
}

#world:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(zvezde.png);
    opacity: $starOpacity;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#world {
overflow: hidden; /*added today to confine the clouds. breaks preserve-3d*/
position: relative;
top:-100px;
height: 150px;
width:140%;
margin-left:-20%;
margin-bottom:-100px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
pointer-events:none;
}

.cloudBase {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 250px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-top: -10px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cloudLayer {
/* display:none; */
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 256px;
height: 256px;
margin-left: -128px;
margin-top: -128px;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="viewport">
                    <div id="header-content">
                        <h1>Title text</h1>
                        ☁ ☁ ☁
                    </div>
                    <div id="world"></div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/oblaki-full.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                10. April 2013  ~  server uptime:  5:23  ~  load averages: 0.32, 0.39, 0.45             </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing looks different between the two (Chrome Dev Mac).  But I am getting a Javascript error that may be breaking your demos. 

Not only do they look different, nothing is happening on them.

Comment: What I get in latest Firefox Nightly: http://imgur.com/a/wWx4I

Comment: What I see:  Chrome Dev on top, Firefox regular on bottom.  
http://imgur.com/F96JBlU

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a problem in the javascript cloud generation. I'll see what can be done about it.

Comment: The cloud generation should work on all browsers now.

Comment: Looking in my two browsers both versions look identical (well the clouds shift between the two).  But there isn't any overflow issues from what I can see.  I might suggest that it could be Firefox Nightly.  I actually just moved away from Chrome Canary (nightly) because random issues would pop-up and I would spend forever debugging it only to have it be fixed the next day with the new nightly.  So if you can maybe try testing on a release channel a little bit farther down from nightly.  That's the only idea I have at this moment.